# Auto-Unsealing of Hashicorp Vault on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I have been trying lately to implement vault configurations on Kubernetes.

I have encountered a few issues and I wanted to ask if maybe there is a solution for that.

my question is where to store the unsealing tokens and the root token?

I saw some solutions where it is being stored in AWS KMS or google cloud.

in my case I need my cluster to be cloud agnostic ( even on premises ) which mean I prefer not to rely on a specific cloud resources.

any idea how I can secure those vault credentials since saving those values in a config-map/secret will make the vault easily accessed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The [Vault documentation on GPG-encrypted unseal keys](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/pgp-gpg-keybase.html) is a good starting point.

Comment: Hi , I looked at that GPG but I still don't understand how to use is in kubernetes without revealing my private key. any time I will need to unseal the new pod , it will need the private key.

Comment: Your trusted key holders can unseal Vault remotely, if they have some network path to connect to the server(s).

Comment: I understand but it is supposed to automated via Kubernetes init container. if the init container will be given the private key to unseal the vault via a volume then the private key is not actually secured. how is it supposed to be automated in a secure manner?

Comment: Hey so just an FYI vault on Kubernetes isn't a great idea. I think around Dec 5, 2018 there was a K8s Vulnerability where remote unauthenticated root access to Kube API was possible. (Have you upgraded yet to patch?) If someone has root access to the machine (and docker/Kubernetes adds tons of vectors to gain root access). They can do a memory dump and get the Vault encryption key, so I don't recommend hosting Prod vault on K8S. My recommendation is host Consul on K8S, and Vault in SCONE Vault Security Enclaves (encrypted ram) on separate machines (Note that requires Intel SGX)

Comment: Also, remember Kubernetes secrets are stored unencrypted in etcd. So it's probably not a good idea to store vault credentials as Kubernetes Secrets. (the names a misnomer, K8s secrets aren't secret, they're just handled a little more securely than configmaps in terms of keeping them in ram.) Storing anything sensitive as a k8s secret would give a rouge k8s admin a potential back door into vault, and if vault was used by an entire organization, that k8s admin could get access to tons of secrets they shouldn't have access to.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I use KMS to encrypt vault credentials and then stores them in etcd as encrypted strings. as for K8s vulnerability , you are correct.